# Are there any known Jedi or Sith Ewoks?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force, sith, ewoks

Are there any known Jedi or Sith from the Ewok species?

It seems to me that any species with enough intelligence is capable of becoming Force sensitive.

[image]

Comment: im not 100% sure how the jedi recruit, but i imagine that the republic/jedi's follow a line similar to the prime directive in startrek. to not interact with primitive/non-warp species. i would hazard to guess that no jedi would go to endor seeking to find force sensitive individuals, since they inhabitants of endor are considered quite primitive(though they are pretty kickass)

Comment: @Himarm That's a very interesting thought.

Comment: i would hazard should they be on endor for some other reason, and encounter a force sensative ewok they may recruit them, but otherwise i believe endor is just a backwaters world out of the way the empire used to hide its creation of a new deathstar.

Comment: @Himarm: That wouldn't work on the Sith though. In fact, in *Vision of the Future*, Captain (I think) Navett remembers the use of a ship-class known as a *Pacifier*, which had the stated purpose of letting primitives know that the Empire could destroy them if they didn't fall into line.

Comment: Spoiler: Episode VII villain: Darth Cuddles

Comment: @Dronz that was my main fear lol.

Comment: Well, in the Star Wars d20, Ewoks are legal for play as Jedi/Sith (although they've got a number of disadvantages that make them a poor optimization choice...) :P

Comment: This does not answer the question, but may help speculate.
In SW:tor on Thython there's a flesh raider( a species of low intelligence ) with force sensitivity.
It is possible to convince the jedi academy there to train him.
I do not know if they succeed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not aware of any Ewok Jedi or Sith in canon.

In Legends, [*Geonosis and the Outer Rim Worlds*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Geonosis_and_the_Outer_Rim_Worlds) shows an unnamed [Ewok Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Unidentified_Ewok_Jedi):

[image]

Comment: Randy Stradley stated that Ewoks were "too stupid to be Jedi," but not until after that story came out, unfortunately. He likely killed off any attempts at using the character in future, though. Good old Randy Stradley.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - given how badly Jedi effed-up, clealy nobody is ever "too stupid' to be a Jedi. Some people may be too smart :)

Comment: @DVK: I think the issue is more that Randy Stradley was too smart to be in charge of the *EU*, so he was pushed out, while George Lucas is too stupid to breathe, let alone helm a major franchise, no matter how well he ripped off *Flash Gordon* and *Dune* (among others) in the '70s.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, according to the first [Star Wars D20 RPG](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Roleplaying_Game_Core_Rulebook) book, there is a distinction between "Force Sensitive" and "Jedi" where Force Sensitive is the ability to use the force and Jedi/Sith is how it was used.

Ewoks in the D20 book were able to become Force Sensitive, but as of Return of the Jedi, no Ewok had been.  It is implied that a Force Sensitive Ewok would likely be a Shaman.  The striped Ewok with the skull on his head, named Logray in the Legends continuity, actually was Force Sensitive in the Legends continuity.

[image: Logray]