# Is there a species that don't have Force Sensitives?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

In Star Wars, we see that the ranks of the Jedi and Sith are made up of a myriad of different sentient species throughout the galaxy.

Are there races in the galaxy that just simply can't have force-sensitives for whatever reason?

Comment: You should note that the entire concept of "force sensitive" was an EU invention; the term itself is never used in canon material and canon material is explicit that the force is just a natural side-effect of life: "For my ally is the Force, and a powerful ally it is. **Life creates it, makes it grow**. Its energy surrounds us and binds us" (Yoda).

Comment: The Yuuzhan-Vong are supposedly without any force sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

### Official Lucasfilm Canon.

**No, none**

There's no mention of *any* species that lack the ability to use The Force within the 6 feature movies, Clone Wars TV Series, Clone Wars film or Star Wars:Rebels TV series.

### EU/Legends Canon.

**Yes, loads.**

The most famous (and obvious) example is the [Yuuzhan Vong](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yuuzhan_Vong) although they technically come from outside the Galaxy to invade.

There's also the [Rakata](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rakata), the [Flesh Raiders](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Flesh_Raiders) and the [Khommites](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Khommite) who assiduously killed all of their "Force Sensitives" (although not with 100% success due to the occasional genetic throwback)

Comment: Regarding the official film canon, didn't Lucas state in an interview that there were two species, one of them being Ewoks, that were "too stupid" to use the Force?

Comment: @JamesSheridan - [yes](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Unidentified_Ewok_Jedi) and [no](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72056/are-there-any-known-jedi-or-sith-ewoks)

Comment: James that statement seems ambiguous. Could mean lack of ability, or lack of understanding.

Comment: Would Gamorrean be the other species that Lucas mentioned?

Comment: @RyanJ - yes, based on EU, at least. Also, IMHO, the EU part of the answer is 100% wrong - the question was about biological ability to produce Force sensitives, so "killing all your Force users" doesn't count.

Comment: @DVK - If you breed an ability out of a species, then it's fair to say that that species lacks that ability. That would also fall well within the realms of "***...for whatever reason***"

Comment: @Richard - Flesh Raiders (who were Rakata) had at least one Force Sensitive.

Comment: Killing off all your Force Sensitives means you *don't* have any, not that you *can't* have any. (The question uses both clauses).

Comment: @RyanJ - I take that back.  The other species too dumb to be a Jedi were http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vulptereen

Comment: @DVK - The sole example is described as a "[genetic mutant](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fashk)". I don't know enough about that game to know whether that's relevant but it certainly *sounds* relevant

Comment: Jabba the Jedi?

Comment: @dvk - http://web.archive.org/web/20080528195105/http://www.darkhorse.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=7257&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=15

Comment: @JoeL. - There was a Hutt Jedi called Beldorion; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Beldorion